# Using proxies in PhantomJS with PHP PhantomJS library

Tags: php, curl, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) for PhantomJS does show how to use proxies. However, how is is used in PHP when using the library from [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/)?

For that matter, how are any of the PhantomJS addons used?

I'm currently doing this with CURL to use proxies:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://$proxy:$port");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

I'd like to do the exact same thing with PhantomJS. I have it installed and configured properly and this example works (PHP PantomJS's own example).

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();
$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('http://jonnyw.me');

$client->send($request, $response);
print_r($response);
```

Where does the proxy info go here?

Thanks. I'm very new to PhantomJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/usage/#phantomjs-options) documentation, section "PhantomJS options". You can add options for running PhantomJS binary like this:

```
<?php

    use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $client->getEngine()->addOption('--load-images=true');
    $client->getEngine()->addOption('--ignore-ssl-errors=true');
```

So you would add proxy information like this:

```
    $client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy=$proxy:$port");
    $client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy-auth=$username:$password");
```

There is also an option for proxy type (http|socks5|none):

```
    $client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy-type=socks5");
```

Comment: this line helps performance and make load faster `$client->getEngine()->addOption('--load-images=true');` by avoiding images load?

Comment: To avoid image load you would obviously set that option to `false`.